# How to have a div inside a column of WebGrid helper in ASP.NET Web Pages?

Tags: html, asp.net, webgrid, asp.net-webpages

I want to have a div tag inside a column in the WebGrid Helper in ASP.NET Web Pages. How can i achieve this. As of now i only know that it takes a IEnumerable as the data source and displays the HTML for the row and columns in the table.

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `format` parameter of the `WebGrid.Column()` method to insert a div, although it will only occupy a table cell (if that's what you actually want):

```
grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
       grid.Column("ProductName", "Product Name", format: @<div>@item.ProductName</div>)
    )
)
```